# An error "System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' occurred in Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll" occurs when accessing Dynamics365

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I am trying to get data from MS Dynamics but an error
 "'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' occurred in Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail."
arises the code is as follows

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IOrganizationService service = GetCRMService();
        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("account");
        query.ColumnSet.AllColumns = true;
        query.Criteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, "ksllls");
        EntityCollection collection = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("name");
        dt.Columns.Add("accountnumber");
        foreach (Entity entity in collection.Entities)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["name"] = entity.Attributes["name"].ToString();
            if (entity.Contains("accountnumber"))
            {
                dr["accountnumber"] = entity.Attributes["accountnumber"].ToString();
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }


    public IOrganizationService GetCRMService()
    {

        string UserName = "mydomain.com";
        string Password = "*****";
        ClientCredentials Credentials = new ClientCredentials();
        IOrganizationService Service;
        Credentials.UserName.UserName = UserName;
        Credentials.UserName.Password = Password;

        Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        //This URI need to be updated to match the servername and organisation for the environment

        string CRMServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["crmserverurl"].ToString();
        Uri OrganizationUri = new Uri(CRMServer);
        Uri HomeRealmUri = null;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        // OrgaizationServiceProxy  ServiceProxy

        using (OrganizationServiceProxy ServiceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(OrganizationUri, null, Credentials, null))
        {
            Service = (IOrganizationService)ServiceProxy;
        }
        return Service;
    }
```

The error is in the line 
EntityCollection collection = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
Can anyone help me solve it

Comment: Can you share the code within `GetCRMService`?  Also, are you able to see the message in returned in the `FaultException`?

Comment: hi, I have updated the code with GetCRMService

Comment: Were you able to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/50604796/7920473

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue and tried to remove and add again the microsoft.xrm.sdk.dll.
The login credentials for your CRM that you mentioned in your code may be different or incorrect. I am saying so because i faced the same issue and found that my login credentials were incorrect so i corrected the credentials and it worked fine.

Thanks,
Shubham Grover